# How do I load a new power app as the default of an existing sharepoint list?

Tags: powerapp

I have tried several options to get my power app set as default. Many of the options on youtube suggest I have to open the JSON code and edit the embedded code.  However whenever I try to edit it, the compiled package fails to upload.

I suspect there must be another option besides "hacking" the code?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to customize list forms using Power Apps or add existing canvas power app to SharePoint site page?

Comment: I built this Power App as the default option of my SharePoint list, however it seems to have gotten detached at some point after trying to use the github feature in power app.  

I went into my sharepoint list and deleted the custom app form (which is just an old version of the current one), in the hopes I could publish my power app and it would take it's spot.  It didn't work, now I have nothing for custom app when I select the "New" sharepoint item

So I am trying to customize the list form, by inserting my existing power app back into the associated slot